# How convert seconds in minutes and seconds (mm:ss)

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert seconds into minutes and seconds with this format "mm:ss"?
I try to use `datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)` but it returns hh:mm:ss format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also make a small custom time class and use `__format__` to control how you wanna print it out:

```py
class MyTime:
    def __init__(self, seconds: int):
        self.total_seconds = seconds

    def __format__(self, format_spec: str) -> str:
        if format_spec == 'm':
            minutes = self.total_seconds // 60
            seconds = self.total_seconds % 60
            return f'{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}'

        if format_spec == 'h':
            hours = self.total_seconds // 3600
            minutes = (self.total_seconds - hours * 3600) // 60
            seconds = self.total_seconds % 60
            return f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}'

        # ...other formats...

        return str(self.total_seconds)

x = MyTime(3674)
print(f'Seconds: {x}')  # 3674
print(f'Minutes & seconds: {x:m}')  # 61:14
print(f'Hours & minutes & seconds: {x:h}')  # 01:01:14
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `divmod` for this.

```
hours, remainder = divmod(someSecondsValue, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

print(f"{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get number of minutes by dividing by 60
and number of seconds by calculating reminder by 60.

```
total_seconds = 10000
minutes = int(total_seconds / 60)
seconds = total_seconds % 60
print(f"{minutes}:{seconds}")
```